# Remove selecting button with Tab-Key on keyboard

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to remove the selection with the Tab-Key on the Keyboard. When you're on a website and there are multiple Buttons and you press the Tab-Key it's selecting a button and adds a outline and when you press enter then it's triggering the button. Is there a way to remove this function on a website. I tried it with `outline: 0;` for `*` but it's just making the selected outline invisible.

Here's an example:

```html
<button>First Button</button>
<button>Second Button</button>
<button>Third Button</button>
```

When you press the Tab-Key then you can see this:

[image]

When you add `outline: 0;` to `*` then the selected Button Outline is invisible but it's still there:

```css
* {
  outline: 0;
}
```

```html
<button>First Button</button>
<button>Second Button</button>
<button>Third Button</button>
```

[image]

### All of this was tested in Firefox Version 92.0

Comment: Did you think about using JavaScript or not?

Comment: @JustChillinInDaHood If you really need it then yes but please no jQuery

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might be able to use a negative `tabindex`, however that is only supported on HTML5.

```css
* {
  outline: 1;
}
```

```html
<button>First Button</button>
<button tabindex="-1">Second Button</button>
<button>Third Button</button>
```

Comment: Hi @Austin this works like a charm! I didn't know that something like that exists in HTML. I will accept the Answer in 5 Minutes. Thanks again ;)